Connecting daisy-chained screens to two different computers via KVM
I have two screens daisy-chained to my work laptop in my WFH setup.
I wanted to ask if it's going to be possible to connect the screens ( or only one of them) to my own pc via KVM switch.
Laptop's output is usb C.
My home pc's output is mini DP.
One of the screens is DP input and output, the other DP input only.
I only need one of the screens (ideally the one with DP input only) for my home purposes, but I'm guessing this will not make any difference.
Thank you for any help and advice.

I have a similar setup. I'm using 2 monitors, a work laptop and a home laptop. I have a CKL KVM switch. My work laptop has a dock, so it was easy to connect both monitors. My home one only has an HDMI port. But I was able to get both monitors to work on the home laptop by buying an HDMI->USB-C adapter. For this to work, you need to make sure your USB-C port in your laptop supports video and data, and is not a charging only port.

Thanks. Slightly different setup but it gives me hope. Laptop's USB-C port does it all - that's how it's daisy-chained to the 2 monitors (USB-C to DP cable)
